# Does Devel::Peek exist as a standalone Perl module?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a clean install of perl 5.26.3, and I am trying to install Dancer2.

Dancer2 depends on App::Cmd::Setup, which depends on Getopt::Long::Descriptive, which depends on Params::Validate, which depends on Devel::Peek.

Looking at [Devel::Peek on MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Peek), it is part of the perl 5.30.2 distribution, and I can not find the Devel::Peek package by itself. The "Jump to version" list on the Devel::Peek page lists previous version of perl, not of Devel::Peek.

Installing Dancer2 on perl 5.26.3 apparently has a hard, transitive dependency of installing perl 5.30.2, but I do not have the authority -- nor any desire -- to update the perl installation.

Is there a version of Devel::Peek available by itself?

Thank you.

**Edit**

It looks like I have a broken perl installation. I have no `Data/Peek.pm` anywhere on the filesystem. When I try to `use Devel::Peek`, I am told `Can't locate Devel/Peek.pm in @INC`.

I'll install from scratch and start over.

Comment: where are you seeing Params::Validate requiring a newer Devel::Peek?  is Devel::Peek missing from your "clean install" of 5.26.3?  if so, where did this clean install come from?

Comment: Re "*Dancer2 on perl 5.26.3 apparently has a hard, transitive dependency of installing perl 5.30.2*", eh?

Comment: If this happens to be RHEL / CentOS, try installing the package `perl-core`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to fix it with the installation of

```
yum perl-Devel-Peek
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It's only available as part of Perl. It's has been part of Perl since 5.6 in 2000.

As such, if you don't have Devel::Peek, you have a broken or partial Perl installation. But this is actually quite common, since many package managers break down Perl into different packages. For example, RHEL split off Devel::Peek into the `perl-Devel-Peek` package. So if we're talking about a Perl managed by a package manager, check the package manager for the missing bits.

Comment: I must have a broken perl installation then.

Comment: Some linux distros split Perl into more than one package. Install the necessary package

Comment: RHEL 8, for example, ship it as a separate package that you can install like this:

`sudo yum install perl-Devel-Peek.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

For alpine, be sure to do `apk add perl-dev` to add additional modules  needed to build some packages.